# sentiment package installation failed from local directory

Tags: r

> utils:::menuInstallLocal()
>   package ‘sentiment’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>   library(sentiment)
>   Error: package ‘sentiment’ was built before R 3.0.0: please re-install it

Answer (score 0):

You installed the very latest build of R (3.0.0). The package sentiment is build for R version 2.14.0 and removed in later versions.

Do you work on a Linux Machine? You should be able to install R 2.14.* with the following shell command:

`sudo apt-get install r-base-core=2.14.1-1`

Maybe you have to install other packages first, like these:

`apt-get install r-recommended=2.14.1-1`

`apt-get install r-base=2.14.1-1`

Then you should be able to install the package sentiment.

But maybe you should look for another package in R 3.0.0 that has the same functionality as sentiment...

Comment: Can you please provide me details for Windows OS.